# Joining calculated sum with specified daterange from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get calculated overtime in my wanted results for each user for a specific period(21st last month to 20th current month, or todays date if lower than 20)

HOURS

```
id  | user_id |       starttime      |        endtime       |      created_at     |
1   |    1    |  2018-05-10 05:00:00 |  2018-05-10 16:00:00 | 2018-07-10 16:30:53 | 
2   |    1    |  2018-08-28 06:00:00 |  2018-08-28 14:30:00 | 2018-08-28 17:00:16 |
3   |    2    |  2018-08-28 06:00:00 |  2018-08-28 18:00:00 | 2018-08-28 17:55:22 |
3   |    3    |  2018-08-28 06:00:00 |  2018-08-28 12:00:00 | 2018-08-28 12:55:22 |
3   |    3    |  2018-08-28 06:00:00 |  2018-08-28 12:00:00 | 2018-08-28 12:56:22 |
```

USERS

```
id | name |      email      |   phone   |      adress      |
1  | jane | gmail@gmail.com | 12312312  | somestreet 12    |
2  | john | yahoo@yahoo.com | 44433322  | anotherstreet 23 |
3  | joe  | joe@email.com   | 12344432  | paradise 223     |
```

This is what i want to do - with the overtimetotal having overtime in seconds for specific period
WANTED RESULT

```
id | name |      email      |   phone   |      adress      | overtimeTotal |
1  | jane | gmail@gmail.com | 12312312  | somestreet 12    |    234000     |
2  | john | yahoo@yahoo.com | 44433322  | anotherstreet 23 |     39240     |
3  | joe  | joe@email.com   | 12344432  | paradise 223     |         0     |
```

I have been trying to do this for several hours now, looking at different solutions here on stack - but nothing seems to work for me.

Basically this is the best i have been able to produce:

```
SELECT u.*, r.overTimeTotal from users u
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT user_id,
    SUM( 
        IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
           , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime)  - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
           , 0
          )  
    ) as overTimeTotal FROM hours
    WHERE starttime BETWEEN 2020-06-21 AND 2020-07-20
) r ON u.id
```

This almost does what i want, but it adds all the overtime for the period for all users and uses it in the overtimetotal field.

```
id | name |      email      |   phone   |      adress      | overtimeTotal |
1  | jane | gmail@gmail.com | 12312312  | somestreet 12    |    273240     |
2  | john | yahoo@yahoo.com | 44433322  | anotherstreet 23 |    273240     |
3  | joe  | joe@email.com   | 12344432  | paradise 223     |    273240     |
```

What am i doing wrong? Can't wrap my head around it. I have really tried alot of things, LATERAL LEFT JOIN and so on.

SOLUTION

I finally managed to solve this with help from the comments

```
SELECT u.name, u.email,
u.id,
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(
            IF(
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttime, h.endtime) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000'),
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttime, h.endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000'),
                0
              )
           )
    FROM hours h
    WHERE DATE(h.starttime) BETWEEN '2020-06-21' AND '2020-07-20'
    AND h.user_id = u.id
) AS overtimeTotal
FROM hours h
INNER JOIN users u on h.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems your ON condition is not completed  (you should join  the user_id matching values) and you need  a proper group by for get each user result

```
    SELECT u.*, r.overTimeTotal 
    from users u
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT user_id,
        SUM( 
            IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
               , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime)  - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
               , 0
              )  
        ) as overTimeTotal 
        FROM hours
        WHERE starttime BETWEEN 2020-06-21 AND 2020-07-20
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) r ON u.id = r.user_id
```

Comment: With your guidance i came up with this now

SELECT users.name AS name,
users.id AS userId, 
SUM( IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000') , 0 ) ) as overtimeTotal 
FROM hours 
INNER JOIN users on hours.user_id = users.id
WHERE DATE(starttid) BETWEEN '2020-06-21' AND '2020-07-20'
group by users.name

This gives me all the users with overtime in the specific period - but leaves out the ones with no overtime. I need the ones with no overtime in the result aswell - any ideas ?